# Conditional Segue while passing data?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to make the segue from viewcontroller to 2ndviewcontroller only when my condition is met. I've connected the segue from the button in viewcontroller to the 2ndviewcontroller. So far I have:

```
@IBAction func switchView(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        // if a and b's textfields aren't empty
        if(!(a.text?.isEmpty)! && !(b.text?.isEmpty)!) {
            a1 = a.text!;
            b1 = b.text!;
        }else{
            // do something
        }

    }

override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if(identifier == "2ndviewcontroller") {
        if(!(a.text?.isEmpty)! && !(b.text?.isEmpty)!)  {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

With this, I've been able to make the segue ONLY when a and b's textfields are not empty. That's exactly what I want but I also want to pass data from viewcontroller to 2ndviewcontroller as well.

```
func prepForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "2ndviewcontroller" {
         let 2ndviewcontroller = segue.destination as! 2ndviewcontroller
            2ndviewcontroller.c = a

        }
    }
}
```

I used the code above to pass data from viewcontroller to 2ndviewcontroller. Problem is I don't know how to combine them to both pass data, AND only make the segue when condition is met. When I have both functions, the bool function executes correctly, but prepForSegue does not pass data. When I comment out the bool function, prepForSegue passes the data, but I'm cannot apply a condition for making the segue.

Edit: fixed by using prepareForSegue method provided in the comments below.

Comment: Why would you combine them? They are two different methods. Once decides whether to perform the segue, the other allows you to pass data as necessary. What data would you pass if the segue should not perform?

Comment: When I have both functions, the boolean function executes correctly, and makes the segue when condition is met. However, the function that passes data does not work. When I comment out the boolean function, I can pass the data fine, but of course I make the segue as soon as I click on the button regardless of whether condition has been met. I've updated my question to clarify.

Comment: Both should be executed. The correct method name is `prepareForSegue`, not `prepForSegue`.

Comment: You are right. PrepForSegue was a method I wrote myself, but after switching to prepareForSegue using xCode's auto fill-in, both methods execute correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Added as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the method name should be `prepareForSegue`, not `prepForSegue`.